# Getting Video To play using c# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, video, iformfile

I am trying to let people save video's on a database, then other users can watch these video's online.
I save my files in wwwroot/videos/Username, while saving other info (name of video, description, url) in a database. Got all of the files to save, but can't seem to be able to play the video's. Did some research and saw that because of security reasons, firefox and chrome, are not able to play video's from your disk. Is it better to save the IFormFile videofile to the database correctly and call it a day? Or is there a way to make this work?

Uploading and saving the video:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadVideo(VideoViewModel video, IFormFile file)
{
    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            string userName = (User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
            string pathString = Path.Combine(@"path", userName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
            }
            int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(pathString, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length + 1;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(pathString, file.FileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                _videoLogic.SaveVideo(new Video(video.VideoId, video.Description, file.FileName, DateTime.Now, filePath, video.CategoryId));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
    }
    return RedirectToAction("UploadVideo");
}
```

Trying to view the video:

```
<h2>Overzicht Videos gebruiker</h2>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="modal-title" style="width:250px;">@item.Name</div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="video-frame">
                    <video style="width:250px; height:150px;" controls>
                        <source src="@Url.Content(item.ContentUrl)" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for getting video in Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetVideosUser(UserViewModel user)
  {
     List<VideoViewModel> videoViewModels = new List<VideoViewModel>();
     string userName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
     string pathString = Path.Combine(@"path", userName);
     List<Video> videos = _videoLogic.GetVideos();
     foreach (Video video in videos)
     {
       VideoViewModel videoViewModel =  new VideoViewModel(video);
       videoViewModels.Add(videoViewModel);
     }
return View("ViewerVideoList", videoViewModels);
  }
```

This code correctly uploads data to my database, and uploads the correct file to my videofolder.
It also correctly gets the ContentUrl stated above.
How can I get this video to play correctly?
Many thanks in advance!

Image of the code: 
![Code]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNhv3.jpg

URL in Chrome: /wwwroot/video/Jesse%20Oosterwijk/WhatsApp%20Video%202019-12-04%20at%2018.04.49.mp4

![ChromeCode]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiNqk.jpg

![FileIsThere]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDjxJ.jpg

[CorrectExtensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Ist.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzF4P.jpg

Comment: You should also provide the code of a controller for getting a video

Comment: Added code of the controller @Mayo

Comment: Please never provide images as for code  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337201/stack-exchange-policy-on-images-and-the-visually-impaired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to solve the problem. Through dependency injection I can add an IHostingEnvironment to my videocontroller. This way i can save the video more easily to my webroot.

Adding the hostingenvironment:

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{

    private readonly VideoLogic _videoLogic;
    private readonly CategoryLogic _categoryLogic;
    private readonly ReportLogic _reportLogic;
    private readonly CommentLogic _commentLogic;
    private readonly UserLogic _userLogic;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public VideoController(VideoLogic videoLogic, CategoryLogic categoryLogic, ReportLogic reportLogic, CommentLogic commentLogic, UserLogic userLogic, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _videoLogic = videoLogic;
        _categoryLogic = categoryLogic;
        _reportLogic = reportLogic;
        _commentLogic = commentLogic;
        _userLogic = userLogic;
        _environment = environment;
    }
```

In the code saving the video:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadVideo(VideoViewModel video, IFormFile file)
{
    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            int userId = int.Parse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value);
            string userName = (User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
            string folder = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "video");
            string url = @"\video\" + userName + @"\" + file.FileName;
            string pathString = Path.Combine(folder, userName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
            }
            var filePath = Path.Combine(pathString, file.FileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                _videoLogic.SaveVideo(new Video(userId, video.VideoId, video.Description, file.FileName, DateTime.Now, url, video.CategoryId));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
    }
    return RedirectToAction("UploadVideo");
}
```

After that you can just get the video from the database and get the url from there!
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

> Did some research and saw that because of security reasons, firefox and chrome, are not able to play video's from your disk.

You can try to access these video files via a path relative to the [web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-static-files), rather than a physical path.

```
Name = "user1",
ContentUrl = "~/videos/user1/movie.mp4"
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Note: when the issue occurs, if you check Console or html source in your browser, you may find the file path looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It seems to now be able to try and get the mp4 file. However it does not seem to be able to find the file, saying the file is not there?
Could you maybe help me with this problem?

Comment: `It seems to now be able to try and get the mp4 file. However it does not seem to be able to find the file, saying the file is not there?` Please clarify more about the problem, and please check the actual url to video file(s) in browser network tab and make sure the file indeed exists under your web root folder.

Comment: When trying to load the video files, it says "No resource with given url found". When checking the url in the chrome console, the url seems to be good. I checked the folder, and it seems the file is there @Fei Han

Comment: Added images of the chrome codes and an image where you can see the file is present

Comment: You can find [the file](https://imgur.com/a/WaXQtUd) missing `.mp4` extension name.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! I was not trying to give false information, but those were old files. Just edited and added 2 new images where you can see the fukes are present with correct extensions. I can also play the video files from the directory, which means they have been saved correctly